# How to fix Invariant Violation errors when running Gatsby build/develop

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-source-apiserver

I am using  `node` **v16.0.0**, `Gatsby` **v3.6.1** and `Yarn` **v1.22.10** as the dependency manager with plugins:

- [gatsby-source-apiserver](https://www.google.com/search?q=gatsby%20source%20apiserver&oq=gatsby%20source%20apiserver&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0i22i30j69i60.3432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) **v2.1.8**.
- [gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/) **v1.4.0**.

I have used the following function on file `gatsby-node.js` to create nodes in GraphQL with images that can be queried later on:

```
// gatsby-node.js
const { createRemoteFileNode } = module.require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = async ({   node,
  actions: { createNode },
  store,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
 }) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `API__images` && node.pk) {
    let fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.url, // string that points to the URL of the image
      parentNodeId: node.id, // id of the parent node of the fileNode you are going to create
      createNode, // helper function in gatsby-node to generate the node
      createNodeId, // helper function in gatsby-node to generate the node
      cache, // Gatsby's cache
      store, // Gatsby's Redux store
    })
    // if the file was created, attach the new node to the parent node
    if (fileNode) {
      node.image___NODE = fileNode.id
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to work normally when running `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` but if I try to run again any of those commands (with same source data) the following error is raised:

```
Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', 
error was Invariant Violation: Encountered an error 
trying to infer a GraphQL type for: `image___NODE`. 
There is no corresponding node with the `id` field matching: 

"27564a59-be49-51fb-98d6-c32de4f2030c",
"379357c0-1faa-5177-806d-7f155f2e3e85",

...
```

Those `27564a59-b..`, `379357c0-1..` are the image node ids that were created on the `gatsby-node.js` function.

If I run `gatsby clean` it will work normally, but **using gatsby clean is not a good solution because cleaning cache will break incremental builds**.

Does somebody know how to fix this error? should I use fixed ids for the nodes?

Traceback error:

```
(/my-project/node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
    at getFieldConfigFromFieldNameConvention (/my-project/node_modules
/gatsby/src/schema/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:227:3)
    at getFieldConfig (/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/infe
r/add-inferred-fields.js:129:19)
    at forEach (/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/infer/add-i
nferred-fields.js:79:25)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at addInferredFieldsImpl (/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/sche
ma/infer/add-inferred-fields.js:63:28)
    at addInferredFields (/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/i
nfer/add-inferred-fields.js:27:3)
    at addInferredType
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/infer/index.js:101:3)
    at map
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/infer/index.js:65:5)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at addInferredTypes
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/infer/index.js:64:23)
    at updateSchemaComposer
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/schema.js:169:9)
    at buildSchema
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/schema.js:64:3)
    at build
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/index.js:105:18)
    at buildSchema
(/my-project/node_modules/gatsby/src/services/build-schema.ts:19:3)'
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Not really, I have tried using fixed ids with 
`createNodeId: id => Image${node.pk}` but still throwing invariant error.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a pretty fresh topic on this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26531).

If cleaning the cache is not a solution for your use-case it seems that the issue can be fixed moving from npm to yarn as a dependency manager.

In addition, try also removing all your `node_modules` and your locked dependencies by:

```
rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json
```

To make a fresh install.

---

According to the error prompted I would try wrapping your node creation inside a `try`/`catch`:

```
// gatsby-node.js
const { createRemoteFileNode } = module.require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = async ({   node,
  actions: { createNode },
  store,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
 }) => {
  let fileNode;
 try{
  if (node.internal.type === `API__images` && node.pk) {
    fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.url, // string that points to the URL of the image
      parentNodeId: node.id, // id of the parent node of the fileNode you are going to create
      createNode, // helper function in gatsby-node to generate the node
      createNodeId, // helper function in gatsby-node to generate the node
      cache, // Gatsby's cache
      store, // Gatsby's Redux store
    })
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    // if the file was created, attach the new node to the parent node
    if (fileNode) {
      node.image___NODE = fileNode.id
    }
  }
}
```

I know you said that running a `gatsby clean` is not an option, but when you are changing the core nodes you may be forced to run one. Once your project is done (first build), the next builds will get and use your cache.

Comment: I am already using Yarn as the  dependency manager @Ferran Buireu (I have updated the question). I have tried your suggestion just in case, but doesn't fix the issue. The same error raised, but thanks anyway, your comments in Stackoverflow saved my plenty of time on many ocasions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :). I will remove the answer if doesn't provide any useful workaround. Just in case... have you tried updating your Node version? It seems you are using kind of old version (the latest LTS is 14.17).

Comment: yes sorry, I am using node `v16.0.0`,  I put `npm --version` by mistake

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your node creation inside a `try`/`catch`? (because of the `onError`)?

Comment: Used `createNodeId: id => 'Image${node.image_id}'` to define fixed ids but same error is thrown: `There is no
corresponding node with the "id" field matching: "Image95,Image96 ...`